# Why spaceEvenly alignment does not work in column?

Tags: flutter

I use spaceEvenly in Column as MainAxisAlignment but seems it does not work, because there are no spaces between the column's children.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(...),
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(...),
                Row(...),
                Container(...),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: either remove the scroll behavior or give the parent container a fixed height. spaceevenly won't work on unbounded height.

Comment: @Doc that works